# Visio stop shapes from changing shapes shape

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013, shapes

How can I make it so that my shapes don't affect other shapes?

For example I have a container for a bunch of use cases, once I put a "use case" oval in it, it stretches the box. If I wanted the box to grow in size I would have changed the size myself. How do I stop it from changing the size of the box when I drop it in?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default containers grow to accomodate the shapes dropped in them. If you drop a shape entirely within the container then the container will stay the same size. If the dropped shape hangs over the edge of the container then the container will expand to accomodate the entire shape you dropped.

You can change this by opening the container's shapesheet and setting the **User-defined Cell** **msvSDContainerResize** to **0**.